# GIDSignInDelegate usage example in a class apart from AppDelegate and UIViewController for Google Authentication in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently using a class FirebaseManager(apart from any UIViewController subclass and AppDelegate) for implementing the GIDSignInDelegate protocol.

Now i can't figure out how to actually show error or open first page after user successfully logs into google account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the method, `sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {...}` gets called after a login attempt. If you followed their docs, it's set in the app delegate, which is where the method will be located in theory.

So here's my solution.

1. Follow Google Docs for setup of Google Sign in (put stuff in app delegate, etc)
2. Set your FirebaseManager to be the UI delegate of the GIDSignIn shared instance (in it's init or where ever you're using it `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self/FirebaseManagerBlahblah`
3. Access the uiDelegate upon successful login from the app delegate

`sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
    guard let firebaseManager = signIn.uiDelegate as? FirebaseManager else { return }
  ...do stuff with firebaseManager!
}`

I don't like relying on the AppDelegate for stuff, but it makes the most sense to follow documentation as much as possible.